# How to Binding 2 listboxes to 1 observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have to 2 classes Principle and Mecanism. 
Principle can have many Mecanism.

In my xaml there are 2 listboxes (principleListBox and mecanismListBox) and i want to select one principle then mecanismListBox should show all the mecanism from the selected principle. When i add a new mecanims or principle all the listbox should be update.

**Models**

```
public class Principle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual Guid PrincipleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Mecanism> Mecanisms { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


public class Mecanism : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual Guid MecanismId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid PrincipleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Principle Principle { get; set; }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Principle> _principles = new ObservableCollection<Principle>();
    private IContext _context;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _context = new BinaryContext(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        foreach (Principle principle in _context.GetAllPrinciples())
        {
            _principles.Add(principle);
        }
        PrinciplesListBox.ItemsSource = _principles;
        PrinciplesListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        PrinciplesListBox.SelectedValuePath = "PrincipleId";
    }

    private void CreatePrinciple_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Principle principle = new Principle
        {
            Name = "principle test",
            Mecanisms = new ObservableCollection<Mecanism>
            {
                new Mecanism{Name = "mecanism test"}
            }
        };
        _principles.Add(principle);
    }
}
```

**Solved**
I used a change listbox event

```
    private void entryListBox_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PrinciplesListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
               //update combo of mechanism.....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried binding the `mecanismListBox.ItemsSource` property to the `principleListBox.SelectedItem` property? You might have to use a converter to map the `Principle` object to its `Mecanisms` property for the binding; I don't recall off the top of my head if the binding syntax will allow you to specify that directly.

Comment: @Petet-Duniho the mecanism doesn't update dinamically

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using a sort of 'backing field' for your currently selected principle.

In your model, add a new instance member and name it something like 'SelectedPrinciple'.

Then set your SelectedValue property on your principle listbox to SelectedPrinciple.

```
<ListBox Name="lbPrinciples" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPrinciple}"/>
```

Next set your ItemsSource property on the Mechanism listbox equal to SelectedPrinciple.Mechanisms.

```
<ListBox Name="lbMechanisms" ItemsSource={Binding SelectedPrinciple.Mechanisms}"/>
```

Lastly, and most importantly, change your Mechanisms property on your Principle type to this

```
private ObservableCollection<Mechanism> _mechanisms;
public ObservableCollection<Mechanism> Mechanisms
{
    get { return _mechanisms; }
    set
    {
        _mechanisms = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Mechanisms");
    }    
}
```

Now any time that your selection changes for your principle item, the mechanisms listbox will display all of the child items of that collection for the selected principle.

Cheers.